# Не подается питание на кулер

Tags: ноутбук

Разобрал ноут (sony pcg-6h4l) из-за того, что перегревался, потом понял что кулер вообще не работает. Заменил мультиметром питание на выходе для него, было 0.9v чего явно маловато, потом питание и вовсе пропало

На этом мои знания заканчиваются. Думаю, полетел какой-нибудь регулирующий транзистор, как его найти я без понятия, кто может подсказать?

Answer (score 1):

найти схему, и тогда уже по ней...без этого - сложно будет